# Exclude support v4 in gradle to remove duplicate but getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I have an old eclipse based project , and i converted it to android studio based. The convertion success, but i have problem when adding other dependency, first i get error `java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2`, because of duplicate dependency support v4, and i try to exlude modul support v4, but now im getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14` 
this is my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':SlidingMenu')
    compile project(':PhotoView')
    compile project(':viewpager')
    compile project(':StackBlur')
    compile project(':FacebookSDK')
    compile files('libs/LibAllShareInterface_2.0.0.jar')

//        Exclude module support-v4 to remove duplicate
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.android.support:design:22.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well although I am not gradle expert and I'm experiencing some problems myself, I was able to reproduce an error complaining about appcompat-v4, using your dependencies.

It seems that you are completely excluding support-v4 from all your dependencies, and since support-v4 is required, you must either specify it as a dependency separately, or change this:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
```

to this:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0')
```

so you don't exclude support-v4 completely from your project.

I did the second and the project could build (A sample project with just those dependencies defined).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case the problem is still there.